# Stop Intents from Opening my Application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an Android Application that will receive all SMS, do some processing and store it in a Database which can later be viewed from my App.

I am using Intent in my SMS receiver class. The main Activity will get this Intent and save it to the Database. My code is working fine and doing everything I require but my only problem is that every time, I receive a SMS, my Application gets launched.

My expected behaviour is that, when the user receives an SMS, the details(name, message and date) should be added to the Database in the background without opening my application.  Are there any attributes that I can use with the intent to suppress launching my application or should I remove intents and use some other alternative approach?

Here is my code.

```
My SMS Receiver Class

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
    {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String address = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        String message = messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().toString();
        long time = messages[i].getTimestampMillis();


        String dateFromSms = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

        Intent newintent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        newintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newintent.putExtra("address", address);
        newintent.putExtra("message",
                m.group(1));
        newintent.putExtra("date",
                time.toString());
        context.startActivity(newintent);

    }
}
}


My MainActivity Class

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    TransactionDataBase DB = new TransactionDataBase(this,2);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        String address = extras.getString("address");
        String message = extras.getString("message");
        String date = extras.getString("date");

        DB.addMessage(address, message, date);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `Intent newintent = new ....` and following 5 lines use the code that inserts into database (currently the code in ur mainactivity), move it to the Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: How about *not* starting your activity? `context.startActivity(newintent);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my only problem is that every time, I receive a SMS, my Application gets launched

No, your `MainActivity` gets launched, because you are calling `startActivity()` on an `Intent` pointing to `MainActivity`, every time you receive an SMS.

Worse, in that activity, you are doing database I/O on the main application thread.

> Are there any attributes that I can use with the intent to suppress launching my application

You should delete all that code.

> use some other alternative approach?

Have the database I/O be performed by an `IntentService`, not an `Activity`.

Comment: Ok, so can i go ahead and remove all my Intent code and make the entry into the Database in my SMSReceiver class ?

Comment: @God_Father: That is not a good idea. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. While your database I/O is going on, if your UI is in the foreground, it will be frozen. Have the database I/O be performed by an `IntentService`, started from your `onReceive()` method.

Comment: Thank You CommonsWare. I have got it working now using the IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

instead of starting activity, just insert into database

you need to change your `onReceive` as following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
    {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String address = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        String message = messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody().toString();
        long time = messages[i].getTimestampMillis();

        String dateFromSms = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

        TransactionDataBase DB = new TransactionDataBase(context,2);
        DB.addMessage(address, message, time.toString());
    }
}
```